# Create a function with two parameters: a list and a string, where the string has the following values

Tags: python, functional-programming

I tried so many things to do this task. I have no idea why doesn't it work. Please help!

```
'''Create a function in Python that accepts two parameters. The first will be a list of numbers. The second parameter will be a string that can be one of the following values: asc, desc, and none. 
If the second parameter is "asc," then the function should return a list with the numbers in ascending order. If it's "desc," then the list should be in descending order, and if it's "none," it should return the original list unaltered '''

def func(*args, str):
    list1=args
    if str == 'asc':
        a = sorted(list1,reverse=False)
        print(a)
    elif str == 'desc':
        b = sorted(list1,reverse=True)
        print(b)
    else:
        print(list1)
     

l = [2,3,7,6,5]    
m = 'asc'
print(func(l,m))
```

I know that I also have to do 'none' for str, but I don't know how

Comment: This site is for reviewing *working* code. You might want to ask for help on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Although in this case it's trivial: you're supposed to `return` from this function. Replace all the `print(...)` in your function code with `return ...`. And your `*args` parameter should just be `args`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok so when you do

```
function(*args, str):
    ...
```

args collects all positional arguments, str then becomes a keyword only argument.
Since you pass the values as a single list instead of multiple single values you don't even need the *

```
function(args, str): # will work just fine
    ....
```

Another thing not directly related to the functionality of this specific code is that you really shouldn't use built-in names like that, even though here it's limited to the function scope.

Comment: Thank you so much)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, but you shouldn't answer off-topic questions.